# get() returned more than one Children -- it returned 2! in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a linked model:

```
class Children(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='child_name')
    blood_group = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)

   class Meta:
          unique_together = ('slug', 'person')

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return self.person.get_absolute_url()

def get_delete_url(self):
    return reverse(
        'member:children-delete',
        kwargs={
            'person_slug': self.person.slug,
            'children_slug': self.slug})

def get_update_url(self):
    return reverse(
        'member:children-update',
        kwargs={
            'person_slug': self.person.slug,
            'children_slug': self.slug})
```

my forms.py:

```
class ChildrenForm( SlugCleanMixin, forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Children
        exclude = ('person',)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        slug = cleaned_data.get('slug')
        person_obj = self.data.get('person')
        exists = (
            Children.objects.filter(
                slug__iexact=slug,
                person=person_obj,
            ).exists())
        if exists:
            raise ValidationError(
                "Children with this Slug "
                "and Person already exists.")
        else:
            return cleaned_data

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)
        instance.person = (
            self.data.get('person'))
        instance.save()
        self.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

views.py:

```
class ChildrenCreate( ChildrenFormMixin, ChildrenGetObjectMixin,
    PersonContextMixin,CreateView):
    template_name = 'member/children_form.html'
    model = Children
    form_class = ChildrenForm


class ChildrenUpdate(ChildrenFormMixin, ChildrenGetObjectMixin,
    PersonContextMixin,UpdateView):
    template_name = 'member/children_form.html'
    model = Children
    form_class = ChildrenForm
    slug_url_kwarg = 'children_slug'        



class ChildrenDelete(ChildrenFormMixin,ChildrenGetObjectMixin,
    PersonContextMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Children
    slug_url_kwarg = 'children_slug'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return (self.object.person
                .get_absolute_url())
```

my utils.py:

```
class ChildrenFormMixin():

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
            self.person = get_object_or_404(
                Person,
                slug__iexact=self.kwargs.get(
                    self.person_slug_url_kwarg))
            data = kwargs['data'].copy()
            data.update({'person': self.person})
            kwargs['data'] = data
        return kwargs

class ChildrenGetObjectMixin():

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        person_slug = self.kwargs.get(
            self.person_slug_url_kwarg)
        children_slug = self.kwargs.get(
            self.slug_url_kwarg)
        return get_object_or_404(
            Children,
            slug__iexact=children_slug,
            person__slug__iexact=person_slug)

class PersonContextMixin():
    person_slug_url_kwarg = 'person_slug'
    person_context_object_name = 'person'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        person_slug = self.kwargs.get(
            self.person_slug_url_kwarg)
        person = get_object_or_404(
            Person, slug__iexact=person_slug)
        context = {
            self.person_context_object_name:
                person,
        }
        context.update(kwargs)
        return super().get_context_data(**context)
```

The children created more than one for same name of same parents. When I tried to edit children it gives `"get() returned more than one Children -- it returned 2!"` error. In traceback, it said,             `'person__slug__iexact=person_slug'` is the direct causes of this traceback.

In the form, I added clean method to catch the error and maintain uniqueness of children name of same parents but it not worked. Could I get suggestions where I do wrong?

Edit:

my Person model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    blood_group = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    present_address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    permanent_address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='member_persons')

    class Meta:
       ordering = ['name']
       unique_together = ['name', 'birth_date']
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? your search obviously returned more than you wanted but what *should* happen? error? return all? one? What have you tried

Comment: This means your get query getting more than one value, because this lookup is not unique.

Comment: I want unique children for each parent. in my model I did it with unique_together = ('slug', 'person')

Comment: @djpro can you post your `Person` model also?

Comment: @vishes_shell, I posted my Person model. It has autoslug field and unique_together constraints and worked fine.

Comment: You should use singular names for your models, eg Child.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I change my model name to Child but still duplicate not prevented.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using [`AutoSlugField`](https://pythonhosted.org/django-autoslug/fields.html#autoslug.fields.AutoSlugField) from [django-autoslug](https://pythonhosted.org/django-autoslug), and you trying to get by non-unique field. `AutoSlugField` won't make your field unique by default, from docs:

> AutoSlugField can also perform the following tasks on save:
>
> - populate itself from another field (using populate_from),
> - use custom slugify function (using slugify or Settings), and
> - preserve uniqueness of the value (using unique or unique_with).
>
> None of the tasks is mandatory, i.e. you can have auto-populated non-unique fields, manually entered unique ones (absolutely unique or within a given date) or both.

So quick fix would be `slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='child_name', unique=True)`

**UPDATE**(Since you posted your `Person` model)

The problem is the same and solution is the same.

Explanation:

For example you have two `Person` objects:

```
id name  slug  birth_date
1  alex  alex  10.10.2016
2  alex  alex  10.10.2015
```

This won't violate `unique_together = ['name', 'birth_date']`

And you got two `Children` objects:

```
id name slug person_id
1  john john 1
2  john john 2
```

And that won't violate `unique_together = ('slug', 'person')` neither

Then you are making query

```
get_object_or_404(
            Children,
            slug__iexact='john',
            person__slug__iexact='alex')
```

Which would match two objects. So you got problem. Quick fix would be to make slug `unique=True`.

Comment: I need child name unique for each parent not all child names need to be unique. So if I use unique=True does it make unique child for combination of parent and child?

Comment: @vishe_shell, I use unique=True in my autoslug field but it can't resist creation of duplicate childs